# Tracking a multicolor object

Tags: python, opencv, tracking

I want to track a multicolored object(4 colors). Currently, I am parsing the image into HSV and applying multiple color filter ranges on the camera feed and finally adding up filtered images. Then I filter the contours based on area.

This method is quite stable most of the time but when the external light varies a bit,  the object is not recognized as the hue values are getting messed up and it is getting difficult to track the object.

Also since I am filtering the contours based on area I often have false positives and the object is not being tracked properly sometimes.

Do you have any suggestion for getting rid of these problems. Could I use some other method to track it instead of filtering individually on colors and then adding up the images and searching for contours?

Comment: Why is this tagged Python? =)

Comment: I am using python bindings to code . I intend to post some code and I tagged it ahead expecting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a full proof track you need to combine more than one method...following are some of the hints...

1. if you have prior knowledge of the object then you can use template matching...but template matching is little process intensive...if you are using GPU then you might have some benefit
2. from your write up i presume external light varies to a lesser extent...so on that ground you can use goodfeaturestotrack function of opencv and use optical flow to track only those ponits found by goodfeaturestotrack in the next frames of the video
3. if the background is stable except some brightness variation and the object is moving comparatively more than background then you can subtract the previous frame from the present frame to get the position of the moving object...this is kind of fast and easy change detection technique...
4. Filtering contours based on area is good idea but try to add some more features to the filtering criteria...i.e. you can try filtering based on ellpticity,aspect ratio of the bounding box etc...
5. lastly...if you have any prior knowledge about the motion path of the object you can use kalman filter...
6. if the background is all most not variant or to some extent variant then you can try gaussian mixture model to model the background...while the changing ball is your fore ground...

Comment: 1) I cannot trust template matching as the order of colors may not be the same and it is slow. 2) I was thinking to use calcbackproject to see if the histograms match. I could not get it to work. if you have a working example I would be grateful to you. 3) Good idea will give it a try. 4) What I wanted was to calculate the percentage of area a given color occupies in a given contour and filter it based on that. I could not find a good function that calculates this. I want to use this as I know that each color takes the same area and there are four colors.

Comment: Honestly, I think GMM would be an overkill. But I would love to try, any samples that I could learn from(I googled but couldn't find something to start working with) I was planning to use simple heuristics like a simple test to check if the centroids of bounding rectangles of individual colors are lying in the contours filtered by area.I don't know if they increase the reliability but will try.(Atleast the train contour can be filtered properly and I can deal with the color variations next)

Answer (score 0):

You might try having multiple or an infinite number of models of the object depending upon the light sources available, and then classifying your object as either the object with one of the light sources or not the object.  Note: this is a machine learning-type approach to the problem.

Filtering with a Kalman, extended Kalman filter, or particle filter (depending on your application) would be a good idea, so that you can have a "memory" of the recently tracked features and have expectations for the next tracked color/feature in the near term (i.e. if you just saw the object, there is a high likelihood that it hasn't disappeared in the next frame).

In general, this is a difficult problem that I have run into a few times doing robotics research.  The only robust solution is to learn models and to confirm or deny them with what your system actually sees.  Any number of machine learning approaches should work, but the easiest would probably be support vector machines.  The most robust would probably be something like Gaussian Processes (if you want to do an infinite number of models).  Good luck and don't get too frustrated; this is not an easy problem!

Comment: I understand that it is a difficult problem and I believe there is no single perfect solution. But I would like to explore the best that could be achieved given atleast with some parameters fixed. Thank you for the pointers, I will definitely explore almost all of them.